# Apply dplyr functions on a single column across a list using piping

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, magrittr

I'm tring to filter something across a list of dataframes for a specific column. Typically across a single dataframe using dplyr I would use:

```
#creating dataframe
df <- data.frame(a = 0:10, d = 10:20)

# filtering column a for rows greater than 7
df %>% filter(a > 7)
```

I've tried doing this across a list using the following:

```
# creating list
x <- list(data.frame(a = 0:10, b = 10:20), 
data.frame(c = 11:20, d = 21:30), 
data.frame(e = 15:25, f = 35:45))

# selecting the appropriate column and trying to filter
# this is not working
x[1][[1]][1] %>% lapply(. %>% {filter(. > 2)})

# however, if I use the min() function it works
x[1][[1]][1] %>% lapply(. %>% {min(.)})
```

I find the `%>%` syntax quite easy to understand and carry out. However, in this case, selecting a specific column and doing something quite simple like filtering is not working. I'm guessing map could be equally useful. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are interested in checking the condition on the first column of each dataframe in your list.
One solution using `dplyr` would be

```
lapply(x, function(df) {df %>% filter_at(1, ~. > 7)})
```

The `1` in `filter_at` indicates that I want to check the condition on the *first* column (`1` is a positional index) of each dataframe in the list.

---

#### EDIT

After the discussion in the comments, I propose the following solution

```
lapply(x, function(df) {df %>% filter(a > 7) %>% select(a) %>% slice(1)})
```

Input data

```
x <- list(data.frame(a = 0:10, b = 10:20), 
      data.frame(a = 11:20, b = 21:30), 
      data.frame(a = 15:25, b = 35:45))
```

Output

```
[[1]]
  a
1 8

[[2]]
   a
1 11

[[3]]
   a
1 15
```

Comment: I'm so confused by what happens after the filter call.

1) what does the one refer to?
2) what does the ~. refer to?

Comment: @Dasr the `1` refers to the first column of each dataset. From your question I understood that you wanted to filter by checking condition on each first column

Comment: What if you don't want to use index but the name of the col?

Comment: In your sample dataset you had all different names for the columns, so I don't believe you could write a generic function for this. Otherwise you can just specify the column name

Comment: Yeah, so if they were the same and say I filtered then wanted to use select, how would that work please?

Comment: If, for example, you are interested in filtering a column named `a` and then selecting that column, you could use `lapply(x, function(df) {df %>% filter(a > 7) %>% select(a)})`

Comment: This works great. The filtering and select works fine, but interestingly it returns an unrelated column with the results that was a factor within the dataframes. I'm guessing this is something strictly associated to tidiverse perhaps. Anyway, I'm sure I can select that out if I need to after.

Comment: Could you explain yourself better please?

Comment: Sorry, once more thing! What about only returning first row after select? Typically use `slice(1)` but it's not working?

Comment: `lapply(x, function(df) {df %>% filter(a > 7) %>% select(a) %>% slice(1)})`. You need a number in `slice` and not a column name

Comment: Sorry, I meant `slice(1)` isn't working after the select call. It's returning the whole filtered dataframe. Why? Yes please, I would edit to reflect the latter comments. Thanks

Comment: In my case is working, I'm getting a list of three dataframes of dimension 1x1

Comment: That's weird. Must be some class/structure difference I have with my actual dataframe.

Comment: It might be.. I've added also the sample data I used

Answer (score 4):

You can use `filter_at` to refer column by position.

```
library(dplyr)
purrr::map(x, ~.x %>% filter_at(1, any_vars(. > 7)))
```

In `filter`, you can subset the column and use it

```
purrr::map(x, ~.x %>% filter(.[[1]] > 7))
```

In base R, that would be :

```
lapply(x, function(y) y[y[[1]] > 7, ])
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks. One more question, say the column  names were the same how would I concatenate another pipe and function. e.g. `purrr::map(x, ~.x %>% filter(.[[1]] > 16)) %>% select(.[[1]])`. Can I also use the name as opposed to index?

Comment: @Dasr Yes, using names you can do `purrr::map(x, ~.x %>% filter(a > 7))`

Answer (score 2):

Using `filter` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(x, ~ .x %>% 
           filter(across(names(.)[1], ~ .> 7)))
```